# Delphi Array with Objects

Tags: arrays, object, delphi, reference

Is there a more efficient way to do the following? Basically I'd like to reference the tMemo name mcpx without referring directly to the object name like I am below:

```
    if x = 1 then mcp1.Lines.Append(inttostr(cp[x]));
    if x = 2 then mcp2.Lines.Append(inttostr(cp[x]));
    if x = 3 then mcp3.Lines.Append(inttostr(cp[x]));
    if x = 4 then mcp4.Lines.Append(inttostr(cp[x]));
    if x = 5 then mcp5.Lines.Append(inttostr(cp[x]));
```

Comment: What are the types of `cp` and `mcp`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a modern Delphi putting the memos in an array can be done fairly easily. Then as mentioned by Sertac Akyuz, access them using an array index and skip the if.

```
Var   
MemoArray : array of TMemo;
... 
MemoArray := [mcp1,mcp2,mcp3,mcp4,mcp5];
 ...
// Zero based dynamic array, so need to do the - 1, no need for the if
MemoArray[x-1].Lines.Append(IntToStr(cp[x]));
```